# Htaccess redirect url path different path

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to masking url with htaccess. I tried a few method but didn't work.
I used this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^em.example.com/lib/view/map$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^pathurl/(.*)$ /em.example.com/map/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Url is

> https://em.example.com/lib/view/map.php

I want to redirect to

> https://em.example.com/map

Comment: Go read up on what a host name actually is ...

Comment: What's `pathurl/`? Explain what "didn't work" exactly. The order of directives matters (the same with any computer code), so placing code at the end of the file that should be processed at the start is not going to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^/lib/view/(.*)$ $1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*).php$ $1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

First rule removes lib/view/ , Second rule removes .php